# Can i access the Inner Class which is not serialized

Tags: c#, java, serialization

I am having a class Which implements serializable interface, it has one inner class which is not implementing serializable interface.

So Can i access the content of inner class at the receiver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with an 'inner class'?

Comment: @Marteen Nested class in C#-pian.

Comment: The inner class still must be instanced in the outer class (property, field, inside a method) before you can use it. The outer class doesn't 'automatically' have an object of the inner-class-type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inner class doesn't implement `Serializable`, it cannot be serialized. Any attempt to do so would throw `NotSerializableException` at the sender. As you would have discovered yourself when you tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No. Any data you expect as receiver need serialization. Inner class must implement ISerializable.

Answer (score 1):

> it has one inner class which is not implementing serializable interface. So Can i access the content of inner class at the receiver.

No. If it is not marked as `Serializable`, it can't be serialized.